# Evaluating the sum $\Sigma \, \frac{1}{k(k+p)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to evaluate this sum:

$$ \sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{1}{k(k+p)}$$

My first thought was to consider the partial sums, and after taking out a factor of $1/p$ from $\sum^n_{k=1} 1/k(k+p)$, I get:

$$\frac{1}{p}\left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+p} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2+p} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+p}\right)$$

As $n \to \infty$, it seems like the series in the parentheses converges to the $p^{th}$ harmonic number, so the series overall would converge to $\frac{H_p}{p}$.

But how could I prove that? I only noticed that this seemed to be that case after trying out a few numbers. Is it even actually true?

Comment: This formula can be used to generalize [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) to non-natural arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(k+p)}=\frac1p\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac1{k+p}\right)=\frac1p\sum_{k=1}^{p}\frac1k+\frac1p\sum_{k=p+1}^{\infty}\left(\frac1k-\frac1k\right)=\frac1p\sum_{k=1}^{p}\frac1k$$

Comment: There's a problem here, since the second term from the right is 1/p (inf - inf). I'm sure it's fixable though.

Comment: Thanks. Does it look better now?